# Supremum of nth terms of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let us consider $x$ in $A = [0,1]$. Since $x$ is a limit point in $A$, we have many sequences converging to $x$.

Now let us construct a new sequence $(y_n)$ such that $y_n$ is the supremum of nth terms of all sequences which converges to $x$ and which are in $A$ (i.e. $0 \leq x_n \leq 1$).

This construction looks decent enough and seems obvious that $y_n$ converges to $x$. But I am confused that whether $y_n = 1$ or not. This is because I can have a sequence whose first term is 1 and that can converge to $x$, so we have $y_1 = 1$. Similarly there can be one more sequence whose 2nd term is 1, so we have $y_2 = 1$ and so on. So I will have $y_n = 1$ which will not converge to $x$.

What is wrong in the above reasoning?

Does $(y_n)$ converge to $x$ or $1$?

Comment: $y_n=1$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ define a sequence $\sigma_n=\left\langle z_k^{(n)}:k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$ by setting

$$z_k^{(n)}=\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if }k=n\\
x,&\text{otherwise;}
\end{cases}$$

clearly $\sigma_n$ converges to $x$, and $z_n^{(n)}=1$, so $y_n=1$. Your sequence $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ is therefore the constant sequence at $1$ and converges to $1$.

Had you considered only the strictly increasing sequences in $A$ that converge to $x$, you’d have found that $y_n=x$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, and hence $\langle y_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ converges to $x$.